# Protobuf-net performance questions

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

1. Is there a noticeable performance overhead in serializing a property marked as a DynamicType (outputs NetObjectProxy)?
2. Would compiling the RuntimeTypeModel to a dll perform better than in memory compilation through `RuntimeTypeModel.Compile()`?
3. Is there any advantage to calling `RuntimeTypeModel.Compile()` manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: you'd have to test with your own data, but it is certainly much less efficient - more space on the wire, and a lot more things to do (type resolution, etc) - plus it can't just JIT everything to a nice simple path

2: not in my findings; it does reduce startup time a little, but the *key* driver for this feature was to allow AOT (although true AOT requires the separate cross-platform targeting thing, which is a little awkward). I'm waiting on "Roslyn code generators" (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/generators.md) for improved AOT support in the future.

3: in some scenarios - yes; for example, you're setting up a service/server, and you want everything ready to go *before* the first traffic comes in, then again - this can spend time *now* to avoid a slight delay later; but: by default it compiles on-demand *anyway*

Comment: Thanks Marc, I really appreciate your answer.